# Can I cut the shower seal that is tearing or do I have to replace the whole seal?

Tags: bathroom, shower, sealing

On my glass shower door, the outer seal of the under sweep is tearing. (I think it's called the under sweep based on other questions I've seen on this site but I could be wrong).

Can I cut the piece that is tearing so that it stops or do I have to replace the whole seal?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back with an update. Based on my answer, I'm surprised, but I'm happy for you. Please post that as an actual answer, then give yourself a check mark to accept it. That will help others in this situation know that this has a good, working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I used Loctite Clear Silicone Waterproof Sealant to glue the torn outer seal to the inner seal.

Works perfectly and it's not leaking.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try removing the door and see if you can refit the seal into the groove on the door, maybe a little super glue to hold it in place. If it is, in fact, torn or split from th groove in the door, then you'll need to replace the whole seal. If you just cut the loose end off, the door will probably leak at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can cut it off so it's not bothering you.

When you do, you'll only have a partial seal left, though, and whatever amount of water that's currently dripping under the door will continue to do so.

If you'd like to stop the drips/leaks, then you'll need to replace the entire seal. If you were to try to replace just the torn off bit, you'd still have the seam where the two pieces meet and water *will* get through that. Water is a bit insidious that way...

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you replace the whole seal. That is the only thing you can do now.